# How to make a link active when dropdown opens?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In a bootstrap navbar, how to make a nav link active 
(just change the bg-color of nav link) 
when nav link's respective dropdown is opened 
or dropdown-menu links are hovered?
I tried the following code

```js
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeIn(50);
 }, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeOut(50);
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav li a{
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 13px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover{
  background-color: #238500;
  color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu li a{
  font-weight: normal !important;
  padding: 15px !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{
 background-image: none;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover > .navbar-nav li a{
 background-color: #238500 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu{
  background-color: #238500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Education</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Goals and Objectives</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Governing priciples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Board of directors</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeIn(50);
  $(this).addClass("hover");
 }, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeOut(50);
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav li a{
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 13px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover{
  background-color: #238500;
  color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu li a{
  font-weight: normal !important;
  padding: 15px !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{
 background-image: none;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover > .navbar-nav li a{
 background-color: #238500 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu{
  background-color: #238500;
}

.hover {
background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Education</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Goals and Objectives</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Governing priciples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Board of directors</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, its working now :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, is that what you want?

```
.navbar-nav .open>a,
.navbar-nav .open>a:focus,
.navbar-nav .open>a:hover {
    background-color: #238500 ;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Just add this style in your CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: if its helps, you can give upvote by clicking on the upward arrow @Muhammad Mohsin

Comment: @viCky there is no such condition, it will work for all menu item.